# How to create a post with Blogger Client library?

Tags: google-api, blogger, google-api-js-client

I want to give a feature in my blog that every one can create post.
That created post should be in Draft(It should not publish immediately).

I couldn't figure out the solution to achieve this.

I tried this:
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert

[image: Log in required]

I need to allow the user with out login in to my account ?

Is this possible ?

Any way that created post going to be in draft so that I can verify and publish.
I don't see any security risk here(I might miss any other case please correct me if anything wrong).
Please help if there is a way to fix this.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? If you find out you can please share with me